# AngularJS & JSON - Obtain Value from Previous & Next Object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

***Background:***
I have created an AngularJS test app which, obtains data from a JSON file, which is separated into categories and within each category is an employee card which is displayed through ng-repeat. These categories can then be viewed utilising a slider (using bxSlider).

***Aim:*** 
With bxSlider you can use custom Next/Previous buttons, what I wanted to achieve was to dynamically display the relevant category names in the Next/Previous buttons (please see annotation link below - my level does not allow me to post images).

[Website Category Slider Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHzLX.jpg)

***For example:*** *the current category on view is the 'Technology' department, the previous button may then show 'Motors' department and the next button may show 'Law' department.*

I understand that the code below would allow me to access the Category name 'Technology'. However this needs to be done in a dynamic nature.

```
{{employees[0].category}}
```

Below this I will include all what I believe to be relevant code.

**JSON file**:

```
[
  {
    "category": "Technology",
    "shortname": "tech",
    "icon": "fa-desktop",
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "card-1",
        "name": "George Sofroniou",
        "shortname": "G_Sof",
        "age": "23",
        "company": "Pirean Ltd.",
        "role": "Graduate UI Developer"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-2",
        "name": "Steve Jobs",
        "shortname": "S_Jobs",
        "age": "56 (Died)",
        "company": "Apple Inc.",
        "role": "Former CEO"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-3",
        "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
        "shortname": "M_Zuck",
        "age": "30",
        "company": "Facebook",
        "role": "CEO"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-4",
        "name": "Tim Cook",
        "shortname": "T_Cook",
        "age": "54",
        "company": "Apple Inc.",
        "role": "CEO"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-5",
        "name": "Jony Ive",
        "shortname": "J_Ive",
        "age": "48",
        "company": "Apple Inc.",
        "role": "Senior Vice President of Design"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-6",
        "name": "Marissa Mayer",
        "shortname": "M_May",
        "age": "39",
        "company": "Yahoo!",
        "role": "CEO"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-7",
        "name": "Yves Behar",
        "shortname": "Y_Beh",
        "age": "47",
        "company": "Fuseproject",
        "role": "Founder"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Motors",
    "shortname": "mot",
    "icon": "fa-car",
    "cards": [
      {
        "name": "Elon Musk",
        "shortname": "E_Musk",
        "age": "43",
        "company": "Tesla Motors",
        "role": "CEO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Football",
    "shortname": "foot",
    "icon": "fa-futbol-o",
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "card-1",
        "name": "Sir Alex Ferguson",
        "shortname": "A_Fer",
        "age": "73",
        "company": "N/A",
        "role": "Retired"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Law",
    "shortname": "law",
    "icon": "fa-gavel",
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "card-1",
        "name": "Harvey Specter",
        "shortname": "H_Spec",
        "age": "43",
        "company": "Pearson Specter Litt",
        "role": "Name Partner"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!-- Slider Container -->
    <div class="slider-container">
        <!-- Search Content  -->
        <!-- controls: true -->
        <div class="content-results bxslider" 
        bx-slider="mode: 'horizontal', pager: true, nextSelector: '#next', prevSelector: '#prev', nextText: '<i class=\'fa fa-chevron-right\'></i>', prevText: '<i class=\'fa fa-chevron-left\'></i>', minSlides: 1, maxSlides:1, infiniteLoop: true, adaptiveHeight: true, hideControlOnEnd: false">
            <!-- Employee -->
            <div class="cards-container" 
            ng-repeat="item in filtered = ( employees | filter: query | orderBy:empOrder:direction )"
            notify-repeat-finished>
                <div class="category" ng-animate="'animate'" >
                    <div class="category-title">
                        <h1 class="title-cat"><i class="fa {{item.icon}}"></i>&nbsp;{{ item.category }}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-cards-container">
                        <div class="employee-card card" ng-repeat="employee in filtered = (item.cards | filter: query | orderBy:empOrder:direction )" dom-manipulation>
                            <!-- Front Card -->
                            <div class="front">
                                <div class="pic-container">
                                    <img ng-src="../static/images/placeholders/{{ employee.shortname }}.jpg" class="emp-pic" alt="Photo of {{ employee.name }}">
                                    <h3 class="emp-name">{{ employee.name }}</h3>
                                <div class="darken"></div>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="emp-details">
                                    <li class="detail emp-age">
                                        <h5>Age: <small>{{ employee.age }}</small></h5>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="detail emp-role">
                                        <h5>Role: <br><small>{{ employee.role }}</small></h5>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="detail emp-company">
                                        <h5>Company: <br><small>{{ employee.company }}</small></h5>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END Front Card -->
                            <!-- Back Card -->
                            <div class="back">
                                <div id="map-load">
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div id="maps-container">
                                    <div id="googleMap"></div>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END Back Card -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- No Matches -->
                <div class="no-match" ng-show="filtered.length == 0">
                    <h3 class="no-matchText">Your search provides no matches!</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- END No Matches -->
            </div>
            <!-- END Employee -->
        </div>
        <!-- END Search Content  -->
        <!-- Next & Previous Buttons -->
        <div class="btn-nextprev">
            <div class="next-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-next" id="next">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-prev" id="prev">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Next & Previous Buttons -->
    </div>
    <!-- END Slider Container -->
```

**AngularJS:**

***Controller***

```
var personControllers = angular.module('personControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

//PersonSearch Controller
personControllers.controller('PersonList', ['$scope', '$http', 
function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('../static/scripts/data2.json').
    success(function(data) {
        console.log("JSON file loaded");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.employees = data;
        //$scope.empOrder = 'name';
    }).
    error(function(){
        console.log("JSON file NOT loaded");
    });

}]);
```

**EDIT**
***Updated Controller***

```
var personControllers = angular.module('personControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

//PersonSearch Controller
personControllers.controller('PersonList', ['$scope', '$http', 
function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('../static/scripts/data2.json').
    success(function(data) {
        console.log("JSON file loaded");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.employees = data;
        //$scope.empOrder = 'name';

        //Next & Previous Button Category Label
        $scope.getNextCategoryIndex = function(currentIndex){
            var nextIndex = currentIndex+1;
            if( nextIndex >= $scope.employees.length ){
                //move to start if at list end
                nextIndex = 0;
            }
            return nextIndex;
        }

        $scope.getPrevCategoryIndex = function(currentIndex){
            var prevIndex = currentIndex+1;
            if( prevIndex < 0 ){
                //move to the last index, if already at the start
                prevIndex = $scope.employees.length - 1;
            }
            return prevIndex;
        }

    }).
    error(function(){
        console.log("JSON file NOT loaded");
    });

}]);
```

***Updated Next/Previous Buttons***

```
<!-- Next & Previous Buttons -->
        <div class="btn-nextprev">
            <div class="next-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-next" id="next"> 
                    {{ employees[getNextCategoryIndex($index)].category }}
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-prev" id="prev">
                    {{ employees[getPrevCategoryIndex($index)].category }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Next & Previous Buttons -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do something like this: create functions to your controller to get the previous and next indexes (to handle the index overflows):

```
$scope.getNextCategoryIndex = function(currentIndex) {
  var nextIndex = currentIndex+1;
  if (nextIndex >= $scope.employees.length) {
    // move over to start if we already were at the end of the list
    nextIndex = 0;
  }
  return nextIndex;
}

$scope.getPrevCategoryIndex = function(currentIndex) {
  var prevIndex = currentIndex+1;
  if (prevIndex < 0) {
    // move over to the last index, if we already are at the start
    prevIndex = $scope.employees.length - 1;
  }
  return prevIndex;
}
```

And then in the HTML call those functions using `$index` (the current index of ng-repeat, see [AngularJS documentation for ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for more details) as parameter:

```html
    <!-- Next & Previous Buttons -->
    <div class="btn-nextprev">
        <div class="next-container">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-next" id="next">
                {{employees[getNextCategoryIndex($index)].category}}
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="prev-container">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-prev" id="prev">
                {{employees[getPrevCategoryIndex($index)].category}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Next & Previous Buttons -->
```

Comment: hi @jmustonen thanks for your response greatly appreciated, like Huy's response it has furthered my understanding of utilising AngularJS and $index variable. However currently, I am not sure where I'm going wrong however the text isn't displaying?

Comment: You might benefit from using a tool like [ng-inspector](http://ng-inspector.org/) - that would help you with inspecting your scope variables.


Of course, you can always also use `console.log` in your controller to debug what is happening inside your functions. For example in this case, you could add something like `console.log($scope.employees[nextIndex]);` to your `getNextCategoryIndex` function, right before returning the index value. And so on.

Comment: When I do the console.log($scope.employees[nextIndex]) it returns undefined. I have installed ng-inspector but do not have a great understanding. Apologies I am still rather new to AngularJS so I am still picking things up as I am developing

Comment: **Update** the text displays if a `ng-repeat` is used. Obviously this cannot be the solution though as this repeats all the categories.

Answer (score 1):

The code you need should be:

```
{{employees[$index - 1].category}} //For the prev
{{employees[$index + 1].category}} //For the next
```

Comment: I attempted this however the Previous was not displaying, nor would it be dynamic in updating the label. However thank you for your assistance, it has helped me better understand the use of $index :)

Answer (score 1):

**Recent Update (09-Apr-2015):**

I have now been able to achieve what I wanted, on click of the button the relevant function runs and loops through the category names. One more thing to add now is that the buttons run in sync.

**Controller**

```
//Next & Previous Button Category Label
    $scope.i = 0;
    $scope.j = $scope.employees.length;
    $scope.nextCat = $scope.i + 1;
    $scope.prevCat = $scope.j - 1;

    $scope.getNext = function(){
        //console.log($scope.nextCat);
        $scope.nextCat++;
        if( $scope.nextCat >= $scope.employees.length ){
            $scope.nextCat = 0;
        }

        $scope.prevCat++;
        if( $scope.prevCat >= $scope.employees.length ){
            $scope.prevCat = 0;
        }

    };

    $scope.getPrev = function(){
        //console.log($scope.nextCat);
        $scope.prevCat--;
        if( $scope.prevCat < 0 ){
            $scope.prevCat = $scope.employees.length - 1;
        }

        $scope.nextCat--;
        if( $scope.nextCat < 0 ){
            $scope.nextCat = $scope.employees.length - 1;
        }
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Next & Previous Buttons -->
        <div class="btn-nextprev">
            <div class="next-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-next" id="next" 
                ng-click="getNext()"> 

                </a>
                {{ employees[nextCat].category }}
            </div>
            <div class="prev-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-prev" id="prev"
                ng-click="getPrev()">
                </a>
                {{ employees[prevCat].category }}
                <!-- {{ employees[prevCat].category }} -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Next & Previous Buttons -->
```

---

---

**Update:**
This is still not going to be a viable solution. I am technically able to achieve what is required however I am still required to use `position: fixed`. This means that the Category label then disappears.

I am now going to try and achieve this without it being within the ng-repeat and using ng-click it will iterate to the next Category name. Hopefully this will be the solution, and I will update upon any success/failure.

**Update:**

I am yet to find my optimal solution however, my current workaround for this utilises @jmustonen's solution.

Outside of the bxSlider I have the custom arrow's (if I placed these inside there were issues with the arrows not duplicating across pages - I believe there's an issue with it when it has `position:fixed`).

Then within my ng-repeat I include...

`{{ employees[getNextCategoryIndex($index)].category }}`

I will then be required to do some CSS in order for this to appear as if it is displayed as part of the Next/Previous buttons. Again these become invisible if `position: fixed` is used.