# AngualrJS - Variable Attached to Scope that Increments/Decrements

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

**Aim:** On click of a next/previous button the label changes to the next/previous category of that current slide. [Category Slider Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBtWE.jpg) of what I want to achieve.

***Background:*** I previously attempted this ['Obtain Next/Previous Value from Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508857/angularjs-json-obtain-value-from-previous-next-object/29509318#29509318). However I had issues where I had to have this in my `ng-repeat` and even though the data I wanted was produced it did not function with the `bxSlider` plugin (I could not duplicate the arrows). Therefore I need to maintain these arrows and labels outside of my `ng-repeat`.

***Next Solution:*** I realised potentially the best solution for this would be to keep this outside the ng-repeat. In order to do so I believe I would have to variable attached to the scope that will increment/decrement. So the appropriate Next/Previous buttons can be viewed.

*I naively attempted `ng-click="activeCat = activeCat + 1"` however that obviously just added ones to the end of the category*. 
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**HTML**

```
        <!-- Next & Previous Buttons -->
        <div class="btn-nextprev">
            <div class="next-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-next" id="next" ng-click="nextCat = nextCat + 1"> 
                    {{ employees[getNextCategoryIndex($index)].category }} {{nextCat}}
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-container">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-prev" id="prev">
                    {{ employees[getPrevCategoryIndex($index)].category }} {{prevCat}}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Next & Previous Buttons -->
```

**Controller:**

```
var personControllers = angular.module('personControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

//PersonSearch Controller
personControllers.controller('PersonList', ['$scope', '$http', 
function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('../static/scripts/data2.json').
    success(function(data) {
        console.log("JSON file loaded");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.employees = data;

        $scope.activeCat = data[0].category;
        $scope.nextCat = data[0 + 1].category;

        //$scope.prevCat = data[0 - 1].category;

    }).
    error(function(){
        console.log("JSON file NOT loaded");
    });

}]);
```

**JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "category": "Technology",
    "shortname": "tech",
    "icon": "fa-desktop",
    "cat_id": 0,
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "card-1",
        "name": "George Sofroniou",
        "shortname": "G_Sof",
        "age": "23",
        "company": "Pirean Ltd.",
        "role": "Graduate UI Developer"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-2",
        "name": "Steve Jobs",
        "shortname": "S_Jobs",
        "age": "56 (Died)",
        "company": "Apple Inc.",
        "role": "Former CEO"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Motors",
    "shortname": "mot",
    "icon": "fa-car",
    "cat_id": 1,
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "card-1",
        "name": "Elon Musk",
        "shortname": "E_Musk",
        "age": "43",
        "company": "Tesla Motors",
        "role": "CEO"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-2",
        "name": "Henry Ford",
        "shortname": "H_Ford",
        "age": "83 (Died)",
        "company": "Ford Motor Company",
        "role": "Founder"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Football",
    "shortname": "foot",
    "icon": "fa-futbol-o",
    "cat_id": 2,
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "card-1",
        "name": "Sir Alex Ferguson",
        "shortname": "A_Fer",
        "age": "73",
        "company": "N/A",
        "role": "Retired"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-2",
        "name": "Bobby Moore",
        "shortname": "B_Moor",
        "age": "51 (Died)",
        "company": "N/A",
        "role": "Footballer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Law",
    "shortname": "law",
    "icon": "fa-gavel",
    "cat_id": 3,
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "card-1",
        "name": "Harvey Specter",
        "shortname": "H_Spec",
        "age": "43",
        "company": "Pearson Specter Litt",
        "role": "Name Partner"
      },
      {
        "id": "card-2",
        "name": "Saul Goodman (James Morgan McGill)",
        "shortname": "S_Good",
        "age": "48",
        "company": "Better Call Saul",
        "role": "Criminal Defence Attorney"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just store each objects data in an array, and have the array index increment or decrement depending on which button they press.

```
var i = 0
    $scope.dataArray = [];

//sift the data into the array
$scope.next = function () {
    i++
};
$scope.prev = function () {
    i--
};
```

Here is an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SVXhxvwJqnO8Uarjkxx2?p=preview

**GSof Edit:**

```
//Next & Previous Button Category Label
    $scope.i = 0;
    $scope.j = $scope.employees.length;
    $scope.nextCat = $scope.i + 1;
    $scope.prevCat = $scope.j - 1;

    $scope.getNext = function(){
        //console.log($scope.nextCat);
        $scope.nextCat++;
        if( $scope.nextCat >= $scope.employees.length ){
            $scope.nextCat = 0;
        }

        $scope.prevCat++;
        if( $scope.prevCat >= $scope.employees.length ){
            $scope.prevCat = 0;
        }

    };

    $scope.getPrev = function(){
        //console.log($scope.nextCat);
        $scope.prevCat--;
        if( $scope.prevCat < 0 ){
            $scope.prevCat = $scope.employees.length - 1;
        }

        $scope.nextCat--;
        if( $scope.nextCat < 0 ){
            $scope.nextCat = $scope.employees.length - 1;
        }
    };
```

This if statement will insure that when the end of the array is reached the item will return to the beginning. The next and previous values are now in sync with each other so on press of the next button both the next and previous labels update and vice versa.

**Again thank you for help.**

Comment: Apologies if this is a basic thing - I am still relatively new in regards to my JavaScript/Angular use - how do I go about storing each object data in the array?

Comment: check my plnkr
You can actually just load the json data like you were and access it by index, as I said.  No need to further manipulate it once you load it.

Comment: Ah sorry now I understand what you mean :)! Such a simplistic solution, on top of this I have placed an if statement which I have included as an edit of your answer. Thank you for your help @tpie!

Answer (score 0):

On ng-click call function and in that function do the increment.

Like this

```
 <a href="" class="btn btn-next" id="next" ng-click="increment()">
```

and in controllerjs

```
    $scope.increment=function(){
       $scope.flag=false;
    angular.forEach($scope.employees,function(employe){
             if(flag){
                  $scope.nextCat = employe.category;
                  return;
              }
             if($scope.nextCat === employe.category){
                  flag=true;
              }
     });

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Anita, thanks for answer. However when I then click it changes the label to NaN.

Comment: can you please put console for '$scope.nextCat' before the line '$scope.nextCat = parseInt($scope.nextCat) + 1'. and comment me that wats it printing for '$scope.nextCat'?

Comment: On refreshing the page it does 3 logs; `Motors` (which is correct), then `NaN` and then `NaN` again.

Comment: what is the value type of nextCat? number or string?

Comment: nextCat is a string in the JSON file it is `"category": "motors"`. This is not necessary to include, that was just one of my previous workings to attempt to have this functioning.

Comment: ohk. I had written the answer for integer , bt now i have updated my answer for that. You can try this. This should work

Comment: Many thanks for your input Anita, currently I have a near working version. When I have this fully implemented I shall update my answer with the completed solution. Again thanks for your time and help